# Instance type on EC2 Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2

For bandwidth of 400GB per month, what EC2 instance should I use if I want to create a video streaming infrastructure to different regions?

Comment: Have already taken a look at section *Instance Types Matrix* in https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any specific answers on questions like this. It is totally dependent on your application.

If you stored the videos in **Amazon S3** and [streamed videos through **Amazon CloudFront**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Tutorials.html), then Amazon EC2 would purely be handling user interactions and web pages, without having to serve video content at all.

For any application, the only way to know how much compute is required is to **test the application under many different workloads** and instance types and measure the performance. Alternatively, an application can be designed to use serverless microservices using AWS Lambda, which can automatically scale without using EC2 instances.